# move element right instead of rotate

Tags: javascript, css

I need to change the movement of the element from left to 500 px right instead of rotate at the given below js.
Thanks in advance.

```js
    var leftItem = document.getElementById('item0'),
    rightItem = document.getElementById('item1');

;(function(){

  var throttle = function(type, name, obj){
    var obj = obj || window;
    var running = false;
    var func = function(){
      if (running){ return; }
      running = true;
      requestAnimationFrame(function(){
        obj.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(name));
        running = false;
      });
    };
    obj.addEventListener(type, func);
  };
  
  throttle("scroll", "optimizedScroll");
})();

window.addEventListener("optimizedScroll", function(){
  
  leftItem.style.transform = "rotate(-" + window.pageYOffset + "deg)";
  rightItem.style.transform = "rotate(" + window.pageYOffset + "deg)";
})
```

Comment: Well then do that ... If you need our help with any part of that, then you need to first of all describe to us what your _problem_ is. Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use translateX():

```
leftItem.style.transform = "translateX(500px)";
```

Sure it depends when you want to trigger it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working fine, but not reached back while scroll up.

Comment: You have to map values (0-500) width current/max-scroll with a direct proportion:  x : 500 = currentScroll : totalScroll -> . x = (currentScroll/totalScroll) * 500